# setState not working for array reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component Inbox and having checkbox in it... But It works on third click... does not work on first and second click... `setState` works perfect but it does't re-render after `setState`

```
class Inbox extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props){
    this.state = {
      checked: [true]
    }
  }

  updateCheck(i, convId) {
    const state = this.state.checked
    state[i] = !state[i]
    this.setState(state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked[i]} onClick={() => this.updateCheck(i, conv._id)}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, isn't it? https://jsfiddle.net/qyvLy3ur/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not really updating the state correctly. setting state like

```
this.setState(state, () => {
  console.log(this.state, '787878787878778787')
})
```

does not update the checked state using state but adds keys with array indices to state like

```
{0: true, 1: false, conversationId: '', checked: [true, false]};
```

You are instead mutating the checked state yourself using

```
state[i] = !state[i]
```

To update the state correctly, you would write

```
updateCheck(i, convId) {
    const checked = [...this.state.checked]
    checked[i] = !checked[i]
    this.setState({ checked }, () => {
      console.log(this.state, '787878787878778787')
    })
 }
```

The problem in your approach arises because you mutate the original state directly, subsequent setState calls may replace the original change and hence you see that behaviour.

According to **[documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)**

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yml4vvlr79)**

Comment: hey... It works... but what difference does this line make `[...this.state.checked]`